# Storyboards and Vertical Progress Bars in One Project

Tags: .net, wpf, progress-bar

I have a project that uses both vertical progress bars and animated objects.

Problem: animating the way I want to (simultaneously altering width and height at the same time) will not work in .NET Framework 4 but will in 3.5. My vertical progress bars, however, will work in Framework 4 but not in 3.5.

What I'm asking is, by looking at both sections of code, could any of you suggest a work around, by maybe coding either action in a different way to work in either/any .NET Framework.

Firstly, here's my vertical progress bar XAML.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar" x:Key="ProgressBarWin">
        <Border
                        x:Name="Root"
                        BorderBrush="#BBC6C4"
                        BorderThickness="1" 
                        Padding="1">
            <Grid x:Name="PART_Track">
                <Rectangle
                        x:Name="PART_Indicator"
                        Fill="#6cd133"
                        RadiusX="5"
                        RadiusY="5"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                            <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="LayoutTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>

                            <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="Width"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
Path=Height}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="Height"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
Path=Width}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

And now, here is my storyboard for a window opening in XAML.

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Height)" 
From="0" To="300" BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Width)" 
From="0" To="300" BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:2"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Comment: Any takers no? Surprised there's not more curiosity about this.